# How can I SSH into a server using public ip address while on the same public address

Tags: networking, ssh, server, ip, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to SSH into my ubuntu home server. 
I have port forwarded my ssh port as well

I can SSH using`[username]@[LAN IP]`on a host that's on the **same network as the server**.

I can also SSH using `[username]@[WAN IP]`on a host that's on **another network**.

But I **cannot** ssh using `[username]@[WAN IP]`on a host that's on the **same network as the server.**

Error:

> SSH connect to host [WAN IP] port 22: Connection timed out

Is the system designed that way or is there a way that I bypass that and just forget the LAN IP and only use the WAN IP regardless of what my host is connected to?

Server version: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Host version: Linux Mint 19.2

I'm new to this so I'm probably missing something simple, I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: I sort of feel like this belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/); it doesn't really have anything to do with programming, but rather with networking.

Answer (score 2):

Check on your Router, Local network can reach the WAN IP, or check your firewall

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate? My firewall for SSH(port22) is open for both incoming/outgoing currently. I don't have any physical buttons that seem to be related to this either.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing.  I'm trying to test remote (WAN) access to my home server while at home, but it just times out.  I'm guessing that SSH cannot go to and from the same IP.

Answer (score 2):

NAT loopback, also known as NAT hairpinning or NAT reflection, is a router feature to allow access of a service via the public IP address from inside the local network.

You are trying to create a loopback connection:

`local -> router -> internet -> router -> local`

The solution is to change the settings of your router to allow for this kind of connection. Not all routers allow users to set this, so you might need to replace your router or flash custom router software on it (such as DD-WRT).